# Getting RESULT_CANCELED while taking a picture from SONY phone

Tags: java, android, sony-xperia

I am having an issue with taking pictures on my Sony Xperia L phone (but it works for other phones like nexus and htc) when it runs as an android activity...

After taking the picture it directly returns back with a result code of RESULT_CANCELED.

following is my code for the application...

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Taking snapshot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        Toast.makeText(this, " camera ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAPTURE_PIC);
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "back from camera...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAPTURE_PIC || resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "now saving..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        img.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

    }
}
```

I dont that this is a code issue. I think this has something to do with my phone camera application.

Thanks in advance.